# Intellij IDEA how to order methods after pressing Ctrl+space by order without already used

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Hard to explain, but I remember in Eclipse there was very handy to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> with builders or DTOs. 
But in Intellij IDEA if I want to fill some DTO I'm writing:

```
Dto dto = new Dto;
dto.
    /\
    ||
 Pressing Ctrl+Space here and see some setter, for example .setId.
```

OK, I'm pressing enter end entering value. Then I want to set another value, not Id, because Id was already set, I'm writing:

```
Dto dto = new Dto;
dto.setId(id);
dto.
    /\
    ||
 Pressing Ctrl+Space here and what do I see? 
 Maybe some other setter? No, the same setId!!
```

Eclipse understands that this method was already used and in 99% of cases there no need to call it again in this scope or by near the same call.

So my question: is there some setting or plugin to make my life easier?

UPD:
I want IDEA to understand that I've already used some method 1 line above and don't offer it any more. I suppose that situation when you need to call some method 2 times in row is very rare. And also it should understand that if I'm writing block of code like

```
Dto dto = new Dto();
dto.method1();
dto.method2();
dto.method3();
dto.method4();
dto.
    /\
    ||
 Here I want IDEA to offer me method5() or method6() but not methods 1-4. 
1-4 should be in the very bottom of the list of offers.
```

Comment: Why not fail an issue into IntelliJ IDEA [official bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)? They are usually pretty responsive.

Comment: @TagirValeev I was sure that I just missed some setting. But if no one know the answer, I will write issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I find IDEA scarily good at reading my mind of what method I want to call next. And it usually just takes a couple letters for it to narrow down what I'm looking for pretty precisely.

But, I think what you may be looking for is the "Sort lookup items lexicographically" option, in the Settings window under Editor / General / Code Completion. This always sorts the list by the name, rather than by predicting a few things to put at the top.

You can read more about it and the other code completion options [in the IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-completion-2.html).

[image: Screenshot of Editor / General / Code Completion / Sort lookup items lexicographically]

Comment: I agree in general IDEA is doing good in predictions, but I'm talking about specific case with getters and setters. I've marked this setting as you told to do but now IDEA just shows me all the methods alphabetically including equals, notify, hashCode, etc.

Comment: @SoulCub I'm sorry, I thought you were not liking the order that the methods were in, and wanted to see all the "set" in one place. If that's not what you're looking for, could you please clarify what exactly you're trying to have IDEA do for you?